# How to compare current time to a time range formated as a string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, time, compare

I have two times formatted as strings in my database, they are in the format 8:30AM and 9:00 PM respectively. Using Javascript, I wan't to get the current time and see if I am within the rang of the two times. How would I go about doing this

Comment: Can `12:00 AM` come between the two times, you know, like `9:00 PM` to `7:00 AM`?

Comment: Did you not look up the [JavaScript date api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to get the current hour/ minute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the start, end and current time into JavaScript Date objects, then check if `start <= current < end`. It gets tricky if the start date becomes less than end date:

```
// The un-important bits
var d0 = new Date("01/01/2001 " + "8:30 AM");
var d1 = new Date("01/01/2001 " + "9:00 PM");
var d = new Date("01/01/2001");
d.setHours(new Date().getHours());
d.setMinutes(new Date().getMinutes());

// For testing
console.log(d0, d, d1);

// The important bit
console.log(
    d0 < d1
        ? (d0 <= d && d < d1)
        : (d1 <= d && d < d0) == false
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
function validNow ( from, until ) {
    var toTime= function ( str ) {
        var match = str.match(/^(\d+):(\d+)\s*([AP])/);
        if ( !match ) throw "str has wrong format";
        return match[1] * 60 + +match[2] + (match[3] == 'P' ? 720 : 0);
    };

    var d= new Date();           
    var current= d.getHours() * 60 + d.getMinutes();
    console.log(current, toTime(until));
    return current >= toTime(from) && current <= toTime(until);
}

console.log(validNow('8:30PM', '10:11PM'));
```